# Invalid configuration object error in simple react app

Tags: reactjs

I have writting a simple "Hello World" code in ReactJS, but this is throwing error. Please tell what can be the problem?

**Error:**

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration
 object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.output.path: The provided value "./app" is not an absolute path
!
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactRouting@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactRouting@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-23T07_10
_18_206Z-debug.log
```

**webpack.config.js** file

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app/main.js',
  output: {
    path: './app',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    contentBase: './app',
    port: 8080
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would Strongly suggest you to use path from npm as below,

```
const path = require('path');
```

and your output should become

```
output: {
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
},
```

That will solve your problem.

Comment: don't forget to do **npm install path**

Comment: Now the server is started but still I am getting this error:

`ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./app/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel' in 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\re
actRouting'
BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when using
loaders.
                 You need to specify 'babel-loader' instead of 'babel',
                 see https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#automatic-loader-m
odule-name-extension-removed
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./app/main.js`

Comment: use `loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]`